# Travis CI for classroom/homework automatic testing and grading

Tags: testing, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci, webhooks

I know I can include tests in the starter code and do automatic testing using Travis CI on Github Push(s).

That said, I would prefer to keep the tests on the Travis CI side - hidden from the students. I am know to Travis CI, is this possible?

I would also like to report the test results to an external database. Is this possible?

If Travis CI cannot do it, are there any recommendations on alternative services, CI or other. I would prefer something with Github integration.

I know I can catch the push event with a Webhook, pull down the repository, and run test on a machine of my own. As usual, I would rather avoid building/maintaining one more system.

Answer (score 1):

Since Travis CI does not give you any disk space, I added a custom script to pull in tests. On completion, I post the results to Amazon S3, see [Uploading Artifacts on Travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/)